# Numbering row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to numbering selected row in mysql. My meeting table structure:

```
id | date
4  | 2014-09-29 
5  | 2014-10-06
6  | 2014-10-13 
7  | 2014-10-20 
8  | 2014-10-27
9  | 2014-11-03
10 | 2014-11-10
```

So i only want to select the date row that greater from today and the result should be like:

```
id | date        | meeting number
8  | 2014-10-27  | 5
9  | 2014-11-03  | 6
10 | 2014-11-10  | 7
```

Comment: Where do the values 5,6,7 come from? What real world value does "meeting number" have?

Comment: the meeting_number should be generated by sql query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join to number the rows in order of `date`

```
select t1.id, t1.date, count(*) meeting_number
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.date >= t2.date
where t1.date > current_date()
group by t1.id
```

Another way using a variable in case you have multiple meetings on the same date

```
select id, date, meeting_number
from (
    select *, 
    (@meeting_number := @meeting_number + 1) meeting_number
    from mytable cross join (select @meeting_number := 0) t1
    order by date
) t1 where date > current_date()
```

Comment: It do not work on me, sorry, actually i have several meeting in my table, so this code return index number the row before it selected, i want the index number after WHERE condition(meeting_id = x AND date > curdate()).

Comment: Thx for fast response Fuzzy, the meeting number do not increase, all of row returning 1

Answer (score 0):

I would not go for a solution that returns SQL results exactly as you desire.  Why? Because it will likely involve a complex query that is not able to leverage indexes properly and thus is poorly performing.  Let me give you a few alternate options.

First.  Simply use two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) As row_count
FROM meetings
WHERE meeting_date < ?
```

And read the value for `row_count`. Or simply

```
SELECT id
FROM meetings
WHERE meeting_date < ?
```

And use a `num_rows` type functionallity to get number of rows (no need to read out the result set at all).

This will give you the number of meetings that don't meet your criteria. Store this number in your application then do you regular query

```
SELECT id
FROM meetings
WHERE meeting_date >= ?
ORDER BY meeting_date ASC
```

And simply start incrementing from the previously stored value to get desired `meeting_number` for display.

These two queries will likely be much faster than a more complex query where incrementation is done in result set.

As yet another suggestion, you might also consider something like this to get all the data you need in one query

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN meeting_date < ? THEN 0
        ELSE id
    END AS identifier,
    CASE
        WHEN meeting_date < ? THEN '2000-01-01' /* Or some sufficiently old date */
        ELSE meeting_date
    END AS meeting_date,
    COUNT (id) AS id_count
FROM meetings
GROUP BY identifier
ORDER BY meeting_date ASC
```

This would give a result set lik:

```
identifier | date        | id_count
0          | 2000-01-01  | 4
8          | 2014-10-27  | 1
9          | 2014-11-03  | 1
10         | 2014-11-10  | 1
```

Here, the `id_count` value from the first row would represent the number of meetings with date less than desired date.  You would use this value as basis for incrementation in your application similar to what is descried with the two query approach above.